# How do I create axes from categorical and numerical data using d3.js (version 7.0.0)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, axes

Context: I am a beginner in d3.js and have been at this problem for a few days; I have gone through many solutions pertaining to similar problems on here but even though I've replicated the solutions as closely as possible, the issue persists.

I'm trying to create a bar chart with both axes using this simple CSV file:

```
Food,Yummy
Apples,6
Green Beans,10
Egg Salad Sandwich, 8
Cookies, 2
Liver,1
Burrito,5
```

I've tried using the following code to create the axes of a bar chart (x-axis: Food, y-axis: Yummy):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Loading data from a CSV file</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    //Defining svg dimensions
    width = 250;
    height = 600;
    margin = 20;

    //Creating svg element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("width", width);

    //Loading csv data
    rowConverter = function(d) {
      return {
        Food: d.Food,
        Yummy: +d.Yummy
      };
    }

    data = d3.csv("food.csv", rowConverter).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    //Creating scales for x and y axis
    var xSxale = d3.scaleBand()
                   .domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.Food;}))
                   .range([0, w-margin]);

    var maxYummy = d3.max(data, function(d) {return +d.Yummy;});

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                   .domain([0, maxYummy])
                   .range([h-margin, 0]);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the x-axis, I'm getting the following error: "data.map is not a function". I can't find any other way to get the different Food labels onto the x-axis.

For the y-axis, I'm getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: values is not iterable
at Object.max$3 [as max] (d3.js:641)
at (index):39" which seems to be pertaining to the d3.max() function.

I'm unclear as to why both errors are existing since I've seen them accepted as solutions on other questions. Any help would be much appreciated by this beginner developer. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: That `data = d3.csv(etc...` is not correct. Just do `d3.csv(etc..` and move everything that depends on `data` to inside the `then` method.